# Sum of $N$ Gamma distributed random variables being $N$ a Gamma distribution random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, summation, random-variables, central-limit-theorem, gamma-distribution

Thanks in advance.

Let $X$ a gamma-distributed random variable having scale $θ$ and shape $k$:

$$
X \sim \Gamma(k, \theta) \equiv \textrm{Gamma}(k, \theta)
$$

with its probability density function is:
$$
f(x;k,\theta) =  \frac{x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)} \quad \text{ for } x > 0 \text{ and } k, \theta > 0
$$

The sum of $N$ independent variables $X_i$ with Gamma distribution will be another Gamma distribution
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \sim\mathrm{Gamma}  \left( \sum_{i=1}^N k_i, \theta \right)
$$

**My question**

What would be the distribution of $Z$?, being $Z$
$$
Z = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i
$$
if $N$ is a gamma distributed random variable and $X$ is another gamma distribution random variable
$$
X \sim \Gamma(k_1, \theta_1) \equiv \textrm{Gamma}(k_1, \theta_1)
$$
$$
N \sim \Gamma(k_2, \theta_2) \equiv \textrm{Gamma}(k_2, \theta_2)
$$

I have the numerical approach but I do not know how to get to an analytical solution

Comment: What is $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ intended to mean when $N$ is not an integer? $\qquad$

Comment: If 
$$X_i \sim \text{Gamma}(k_1,\theta_1) $$
$$Z = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \sim  \text{Gamma}(Nk_1,\theta_1)$$
$$N \sim \text{Gamma}(k_2,\theta_2)$$


You can change this into (using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009938/probability-density-function-of-scaled-gamma-random-variable):

$$Z = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \sim  \text{Gamma}(N^\prime,\theta_1)$$
$$N^\prime \sim \text{Gamma}(k_2,\theta_2/k_1)$$

So basically you are compounding two Gamma distributions where the prior for the shape parameter of the one Gamma distributed variable is given by another Gamma distributed variable?

Comment: and indeed your sum $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ is actually not gonna work (as Michael Hardy noted, because N is not an integer) but you can work with the $Z \sim \text{Gamma}(Nk_1,\theta_1)$ expression.